# Release step in VSTS

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I'm trying to release an ASP.NET MVC application to Azure App Services, I created an Azure Resource Manager Endpoint for that and I end up with this error:

[image]

I nead a clear walkthrough of how to deploy an ASP.NET MVC application to Azure from Visual Studio Team Services.

Answer (score 0):

Check this walkthrough: [Deploy ASP.NET apps to Azure web apps](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/examples/azure/azure-web-apps-from-build-and-release-hubs)

Comment: I've already followed it and I'm stuck with at the end point creation, for that  reason I'm asking for a detailed step by step walkthough better than this msdn one wich leads to nothing in reality